# Which of the following is called to apply taxes on the product view page?

Tags: tax, magento-enterprise

Which of the following is called to apply taxes on the product view page?

1. Mage_Tax_Helper_Data
2. Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Tax
3. Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Tax
4. Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price

Answer (score 2):

The product view page will use the `Mage_Tax_Helper_Data` to apply the tax on the price.

For example to display the minimal price it does the following:

```
$_simplePricesTax = ($_taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax() || $_taxHelper->displayBothPrices());
$_minimalPriceValue = $_product->getMinimalPrice();
$_minimalPrice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_minimalPriceValue, $_simplePricesTax);
```

`$_simplePricesTax` is a boolean based on if the price includes tax or if you should display both prices,

`$_minimalPriceValue` is the price saved against the price,

`$_minimalPrice` is the price after all the tax settings have been processed,